# Is it possible to make your REST API redirect link dynamic/configurable?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have a REST API on Enterprise Integrator that uses a db lookup mediator to search a microsoft sql server database and redirects based on the whether or not the data exists in the db. I need to make the redirect part of the code configurable/dynamic as it wouldn't make sense to constantly update the url and redeploy every time the url changes.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="DBLookupAPI" context="/dblookup">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{UserCode}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value" expression="get-property('uri.var.UserCode')"/>
         </log>
         <dblookup>
            <connection>
               <pool>
                  <driver>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver>
                  <url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.1.1.111\test;databaseName=UserDB</url>
                  <user>admin</user>
                  <password>admin</password>
               </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
               <sql>select UserCode from UserDB.dbo.Users where UserCode =?;</sql>
               <parameter expression="get-property('uri.var.UserCode ')" type="CHAR"/>
               <result name="foundnr" column="UserCode "/>
            </statement>
         </dblookup>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="Value" expression="get-property('foundnr')"/>
         </log>
         <filter source="boolean(get-property('foundnr'))" regex="true">
            <then>
               <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Exists Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://wso2.com/" scope="transport"/>
            </then>
            <else>
               <log>
                  <property name="Message" value="Name Does Not Exist Lets redirect"/>
               </log>
               <property name="HTTP_SC" value="302"/>
               <property name="Location" value="https://www.youtube.com/" scope="transport"/>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property mediator as below.

```
<property name="Location" expression="get-property('registry','REGISTRY_PATH')"/>
```

Below are the possible options for get-property method.

1. Read from registry

> get-property('registry', String registryPath@propertyName)

> get-property('registry', String registryPath)

2. Read from Java System property

> get-property('system', String propertyName)

3. Read from the environment

> get-property('env', String propertyName)

4. Read from a file

> get-property('file', String propertyName)

5. Read from the context

You can use the class mediator or any other mediator and set the redirect url to the context and use the following property mediator to retrieve it from the context.

```
<property name="Location" expression="$ctx:ERROR_MESSAGE"/>
```

Please refer the documentation - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/accessing-properties-with-xpath/#get-property-function

Comment: Thank you, I have used the read from environment approach and it has worked successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. One way is to read from environment variables. In the following example the `Location` property is set from the environment variable named `REDIRECT_URL`.

```xml
<property name="Location" expression="get-property('env','REDIRECT_URL')" scope="transport"/>
```